# Array is deleting the last object in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Here is my main view controller. I am populating a custom calendar with events from an xml file. This is working fine... Im also adding my own events. I use the same array for both. It appears that when I add a new event to the array. It deletes the previous one.

```
      #import "CalendarViewController.h"
      #import "HeaderCollectionReusableView.h"
      #import "CalendarCollectionViewCell.h"
      #import "EventViewController.h"
      #import "AppDelegate.h"
      #import "events.h"
      #import "AddViewController.h"


   @interface CalendarViewController ()

    @end

@implementation CalendarViewController

UIImageView *navBarHairlineImageView;
BOOL _viewDidLayoutSubviewsForTheFirstTime = YES;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

 NSLog(@"VIEW DID LOAD");
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 self.title = @"Calendar";
//\n in xml is encoded as &#10;


_viewDidLayoutSubviewsForTheFirstTime = YES;

if (!_calendar) {
    [self setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];
}

_date = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSDateComponents *components = [_calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:_date];

// set calendar from 2000 to current year + 10 years range


long year = components.year;
long month = components.month;
long day = components.day;

//  NSLog(@"%ld %ld %ld", day, month, year);

_initialSection = (year - 2000) * 12 + month - 1; // index sections start at 0

components.day = 1;
components.month = 1;
components.year = 2000;
_firstDate = [_calendar dateFromComponents:components];

components.year = year + 10;
components.day = -1;
_lastDate = [_calendar dateFromComponents:components];

UINavigationBar *navigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
navBarHairlineImageView = [self findHairlineImageViewUnder:navigationBar];

UIView *bottomBorder = [[UIView alloc] init];
bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, _days.frame.size.height - 0.5, _days.frame.size.width, 0.5);
[_days addSubview:bottomBorder];


AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSData *data = appDelegate.data;


NSString *a = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *b = [a stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#10;" withString:@"\n"];
data = [b dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//NSLog(@"%@", b);

_eventParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
_eventsA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[_eventParser setDelegate:self];
[_eventParser parse];



NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = dirPaths[0];

_databasesPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ev.db"]];

//  NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

const char *dbpaths = [_databasesPath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if(sqlite3_open(dbpaths, &_myDB) == SQLITE_OK){
    NSString *querySQL = @"SELECT * FROM event";
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"I SEE YOUFIRST");


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_myDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
        // const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        //query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        // NSMutableArray *allMessages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"I SEE YOU");

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_myDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){
                NSString *typeField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char * ) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                NSString *descriptionField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char * ) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                NSString *dateField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char * ) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];


                // NSLog(@"%@", dateField);
                // NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: typeField, @"typeField", descriptionField, @"descriptionField", dateField, @"dateField", nil];
                // [allMessages addObject:dict];



                _currentevent.eventType = typeField; //[dict objectForKey:@"typeField"];
                _currentevent.eventDate = dateField; //[dict objectForKey:@"dateField"];
                _currentevent.eventDescription = descriptionField; //[dict objectForKey:@"descriptionField"];

                if (![_eventsA containsObject:_currentevent]){
                    [self.eventsA addObject:_currentevent];

                }
               // NSLog(@"Type: %@ Description:%@ Date:%@" , typeField, descriptionField, dateField );

                //[_eventsA addObject:dateField];
                // [_eventsA addObject:nameField];
                //[_eventsA addObject:typeField];
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        }
        sqlite3_close(_myDB);
    }

}
else {
    NSLog (@"Failed to add event");
}


NSLog(@"%lu" , (unsigned long)[_eventsA count]);

for(int i = 0; i < [_eventsA count]; i++) {
    events *ex = [_eventsA objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *ds = ex.eventDate;
    NSString *dd = ex.eventDescription;
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", ds, dd);
}






  }




 - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
// Only scroll when the view is rendered for the first time
if (_viewDidLayoutSubviewsForTheFirstTime) {
    _viewDidLayoutSubviewsForTheFirstTime = NO;

UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [_calendarCollectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:_initialSection]];

    CGRect rect = attributes.frame;
    [_calendarCollectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(_calendarCollectionView.frame.origin.x, rect.origin.y - 32) animated:NO];
}

 }

 // find and remove hairline image under top bar

- (UIImageView *)findHairlineImageViewUnder:(UIView *)view {
if ([view isKindOfClass:UIImageView.class] && view.bounds.size.height <= 1.0) {
    return (UIImageView *)view;
}
for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [self findHairlineImageViewUnder:subview];
    if (imageView) {
        return imageView;
    }
}
return nil;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
navBarHairlineImageView.hidden = YES;
[self viewDidLoad];



 }

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
navBarHairlineImageView.hidden = NO;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UICollectionViewDataSource

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
return [_calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:_firstDate toDate:_lastDate options:0].month + 1;
 }

   -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

NSDate *firstOfMonth = [self firstOfMonthForSection:section];
NSRange rangeOfWeeks = [_calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth forDate:firstOfMonth];

//We need the number of calendar weeks for the full months (it will maybe include previous month and next months cells)

int daysPerWeek = 7;
return (rangeOfWeeks.length * daysPerWeek);
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CalendarCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"calendarCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDate *firstOfMonth = [self firstOfMonthForSection:indexPath.section];
NSDate *cellDate = [self dateForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDateComponents *cellDateComponents = [_calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:cellDate];

NSDateComponents *firstOfMonthsComponents = [_calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:firstOfMonth];

NSDateComponents *todayComponents = [_calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date]];

if(cellDateComponents.month == firstOfMonthsComponents.month) {
    NSString *day = @"";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"d";
    day = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:cellDate];
    cell.dateNumber.text = day;

    cell.dateNumber.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0;
    cell.dateNumber.clipsToBounds = YES;

    if(cellDateComponents.day == todayComponents.day &&
       cellDateComponents.month == todayComponents.month &&
       cellDateComponents.year == todayComponents.year) {

        cell.dateNumber.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.dateNumber.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    else {
        cell.dateNumber.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.dateNumber.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        if(indexPath.row % 7 == 0 || (indexPath.row + 1) % 7 == 0)
            cell.dateNumber.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        else
            cell.dateNumber.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }


    cell.event.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
    cell.event.clipsToBounds = YES;

    NSDateFormatter *eventFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    eventFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
    NSString *dateCell = [eventFormatter stringFromDate:cellDate];

    NSString *markedEvent = @"";



    for(int i = 0; i < [_eventsA count]; i++) {
        events *temp = [_eventsA objectAtIndex:i];
        markedEvent = temp.eventDate;

        if([markedEvent isEqualToString:dateCell]) {
            cell.event.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            cell.hasEvent = YES;
        }
    }




}
else {
    cell.dateNumber.text = @"";
}

cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;


return cell;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate

 - (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
NSDate *firstOfMonth = [self firstOfMonthForSection:indexPath.section];
NSDate *cellDate = [self dateForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//We don't want to select Dates that are "disabled"
if (![self isEnabledDate:cellDate]) {
    return NO;
}

NSDateComponents *cellDateComponents = [_calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay|NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:cellDate];
NSDateComponents *firstOfMonthsComponents = [_calendar components:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:firstOfMonth];

return (cellDateComponents.month == firstOfMonthsComponents.month);
      }

       - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 CalendarCollectionViewCell *cell = (CalendarCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.dateNumber.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0;
cell.dateNumber.clipsToBounds = YES;
cell.dateNumber.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
cell.dateNumber.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

_selectedDate = [self dateForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell.hasEvent) {

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"EEEE MMMM d, yyyy";
    NSDate *cellDate = [self dateForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *stringDate = [formatter stringFromDate:cellDate];
    NSString *stringType;
    NSString *stringDescription;
    NSString *tempDate;
    NSDateFormatter *fm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    fm.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
    NSString *cd = [fm stringFromDate:cellDate];

    for(int i = 0; i <[_eventsA count]; i++){
        events *temp1 = [_eventsA objectAtIndex:i];
        tempDate = temp1.eventDate;
        //NSLog(@"%@", tempDate);
        // NSLog(@"%@", stringDate);
      //   NSLog(@"%@", cd);



    if([cd isEqualToString:tempDate]){
     //NSLog(@"%@", tempDate);


        stringType= temp1.eventType;
        stringDescription = temp1.eventDescription;


    }
    else{


    }
    }

    EventViewController *events = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"eventController"];

    events.stringDate = stringDate;
    events.stringType = stringType;
    events.stringDescription = stringDescription;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:events animated:YES];
}
 }

 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     CalendarCollectionViewCell *cell =(CalendarCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDate *cellDate = [self dateForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if([self isTodayDate:cellDate]) {
    cell.dateNumber.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.dateNumber.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
else {
    cell.dateNumber.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.dateNumber.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
}





   - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
   UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
    HeaderCollectionReusableView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"calendarHeader" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:12];
    headerView.month.font = font;
    headerView.month.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIView *bottomBorder = [UIView new];
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, headerView.frame.size.height - 1, headerView.frame.size.width, 1);
    [headerView addSubview:bottomBorder];

    NSDateFormatter *headerDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    headerDateFormatter.calendar = _calendar;
    headerDateFormatter.dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"yyyy LLLL" options:0 locale:_calendar.locale];

    NSString *headerTitle = [headerDateFormatter stringFromDate:[self firstOfMonthForSection:indexPath.section]].uppercaseString;

    headerView.month.text = headerTitle;
    reusableview = headerView;

}

return reusableview;

}

  - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width / 7.0;
CGFloat height = width;

return CGSizeMake(width, height);
 }

 - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (id)self.calendarCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;

[flowLayout invalidateLayout]; //force the elements to get laid out again with the new size
 }

           // Calendar methods

    - (NSDate *)firstOfMonthForSection:(NSInteger)section
         {
        NSDateComponents *offset = [NSDateComponents new];
        offset.month = section;

    return [_calendar dateByAddingComponents:offset toDate:_firstDate options:0];
      }

      - (NSDate *)dateForCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
          NSDate *firstOfMonth = [self firstOfMonthForSection:indexPath.section];
             NSInteger ordinalityOfFirstDay = [_calendar ordinalityOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay inUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth forDate:firstOfMonth];
      NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
          dateComponents.day = (1 - ordinalityOfFirstDay) + indexPath.item;

       return [_calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:firstOfMonth options:0];
     }

  - (BOOL)isEnabledDate:(NSDate *)date
      {
           NSDate *clampedDate = [self clampDate:date toComponents:(NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay)];
                if (([clampedDate compare:_firstDate] == NSOrderedAscending) || ([clampedDate compare:_lastDate] == NSOrderedDescending)) {
               return NO;
          }

       return YES;
     }

      - (NSDate *)clampDate:(NSDate *)date toComponents:(NSUInteger)unitFlags
        {
             NSDateComponents *components = [_calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
           return [_calendar dateFromComponents:components];
         }

        - (BOOL)isTodayDate:(NSDate *)date
         {
          return [self clampAndCompareDate:date withReferenceDate:[NSDate date]];
       }

      - (BOOL)isSelectedDate:(NSDate *)date
         {
         if (!_selectedDate) {
            return NO;
                 }
                                    return [self clampAndCompareDate:date withReferenceDate:_selectedDate];
                 }


                     - (BOOL)clampAndCompareDate:(NSDate *)date withReferenceDate:(NSDate *)referenceDate
             {
            NSDate *refDate = [self clampDate:referenceDate toComponents:(NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay)];
             NSDate *clampedDate = [self clampDate:date toComponents:(NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay)];

           return [refDate isEqualToDate:clampedDate];
        }


         #pragma mark - NSXMLParser Delegate


        - (void) parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
              }


                - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

       if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"event"])
          _currentevent = [[events alloc] init];

                }

                 -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
                          _currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
                  }

                - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {


          if([elementName isEqualToString:@"type"]) {
         _currentevent.eventType = _currentNodeContent;
         }

       if([elementName isEqualToString:@"date"]) {
            _currentevent.eventDate = _currentNodeContent;
          }

        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
           _currentevent.eventDescription = _currentNodeContent;
          }


         if([elementName isEqualToString:@"event"]) {
        [_eventsA addObject:_currentevent];
      }




     }

     - (void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
     }

      #pragma mark - Navigation

        // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
       // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueAdd"]) {
        AddViewController *modalVC = (AddViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
       // modalVC.cVC = self;
        modalVC.sDate = _selectedDate;


          }
     }



         - (IBAction)todayButton:(id)sender {

          UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [_calendarCollectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:_initialSection]];

          CGRect rect = attributes.frame;
          [_calendarCollectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(_calendarCollectionView.frame.origin.x, rect.origin.y - 32) animated:YES];

          }

             - (IBAction)addButton:(id)sender {
           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueAdd" sender:self];
        }

                 @end
```

This is my view controller where I'm adding events to sqlite

```
        #import "AddViewController.h"
        #import "CalendarViewController.h"

         @interface AddViewController ()

           @end

         @implementation AddViewController

          - (void)viewDidLoad {
          [super viewDidLoad];

          NSLog(@"This is the Date:%@", _sDate);
                   NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *docsDir = dirPaths[0];

             // Build the path to the database file
        _databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ev.db"]];




           NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

            if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _databasePath ] == NO) {
           const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
     _status.text = @"No TABLE";

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_evDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EVENT (TYPE TEXT, DESCRIPTION TEXT, DATE VARCHAR(255))";

        if (sqlite3_exec(_evDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
            _status.text = @"Failed to create table";
        }
        sqlite3_close(_evDB);
    } else {
        _status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
          }
          }
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

      // [CalendarViewController.view.eventsA addObject:_currentevent];
         }

      - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event {
      UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

     if ([_etype isFirstResponder] && (_etype != touch.view)) {
    // _inputText lost focus - close keyboard
    [_etype resignFirstResponder];
         }

           if ([_edescription isFirstResponder] && (_edescription != touch.view))                         {
          // _inputText lost focus - close keyboard
        [_edescription resignFirstResponder];
                  }



       [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
          }

              - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
             [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
         }


             #pragma mark - Navigation

             // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
      - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
       // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
         // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"goBack"]) {

        CalendarViewController *destViewController = (CalendarViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;


        destViewController.myDB = _evDB;
         destViewController.databasesPath = _databasePath;
         destViewController.eventDate = _cd;
        destViewController.eventType = _type1;
        destViewController.eventDescription = _d1;
        destViewController.eventsA = _mArray;


         }

         }


        - (IBAction)addEvent:(id)sender {

         // NSMutableArray *temporaryArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:_sDate];
      //= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:selectedRow];
    // NSLog(@"%@", _sDate);
     //NSLog(@"%@", type);
     //NSLog(@"%@", description);
      //_cVC.eventsA = temporaryArray;

      _type1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[_etype text]];
       _d1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[_edescription text]];

     // NSLog(@"%@", type1);
    //NSLog(@"%@", description);


     sqlite3_stmt *statement;
      const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];

     NSDateFormatter *fm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     fm.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
      _cd = [fm stringFromDate:_sDate];

    NSLog(@"%@" , _cd);




    // save

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_evDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO EVENT VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", _type1, _d1, _cd];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(_evDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            _status.text = @"Event added";
            _etype.text = @"";
            _edescription.text = @"";


           // UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            /*CalendarViewController *destViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
            destViewController.myDB = _myDB;
            destViewController.databasesPath = _databasePath;
            destViewController.eventDate = cd;
            destViewController.eventType = type1;
            destViewController.eventDescription = description;
            */
           // super.navigationController.viewDidLoad;



          [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goBack" sender:self];

           // CalendarViewController *cal = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];



            //[self.navigationController pushViewController:cal animated:YES];

          //  _cevent.eventType =_type1;
            //_cevent.eventDate = _cd;
            //_cevent.eventDescription = _d1;

            //[_mArray addObject:_cevent];







        } else {
            _status.text = @"Failed to add event";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        sqlite3_close(_evDB);
    }
    }

     @end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You have one down vote so far on your question, you will probably get more. You need to be clear and precise about what you are asking, post the minimal code that reproduces the problem, say what you've tried, etc. In short you need to help people to help you! Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then delete this question (which will remove those down votes) and open a new one, somebody will then undoubtedly help you out. HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
if (![_eventsA containsObject:_currentevent]) {
    [self.eventsA addObject:_currentevent];
```

Problem 1. After one `[self.eventsA addObject:_currentevent]`, `[_eventsA containsObject:_currentevent]` will return `YES`.

Problem 2. `NSMutableArray` stores pointers to objects and doesn't copy an object when it is added. If you add `_currentevent` to `self.eventsA` and then change the properties of `_currentevent`, the properties of the added `_currentevent` will change. If you remove `if (![_eventsA containsObject:_currentevent])` and keep adding the same object, which is possible, all elements of `_eventsA` will have the properties of the last `_currentevent`.

Solution: create a new local event object in each iteration of the while loop.